# Woocommerce not override page.php with woocommerce.php

Tags: php, wordpress, integration, woocommerce, theming

I have a custom wp theme, and want to integrate it with woocommerce.

I need to fully customize page, which wc is included(delete sidebar, post date e.t.c)

I created duplicate of page.php and named it as woocommerce.php, but it not override standard page template and fully ignores woocommerce.php. What I doing wrong?

P.S Path to woocommerce.php **/wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce.php**
P.P.S Wordpress 3.8.1, Woocommerce 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once:

You need to add it to your theme folder  - also you need to name the template file like this

```
<?php/*Template Name: Woocommerce Template */ ?>
```

Then on each page that it uses for example shop etc use this new template file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Still not works :(
Woocommerce don't use my woocommerce.php file.
How I can manually set the template on wc files?
I have copies of wc templates in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce. This override works, but not with main template(woocommerce.php).

Comment: Show me a link if you can!